# List View Item Click listener not working

Tags: android

Row layout for list view . the click on the items is not working. 
the list.onItemClickListener function is not getting called even though there is no error or crash.There is some issue with it which im not able to figure out.

XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/invoice_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/invoice_image"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/report_card_symbol"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:focusable="false"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/order_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/invoice_image"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/invoice_amount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/order_id"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/invoice_image"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right_new"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Share your java code

Comment: I do not see any listView element in this XML code.

Comment: Please post you java code, bcz we can't understand what is problem without your java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed the focussable on the parent relative layout resolved the issue. The focus was on relative layout so the click on the list didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Check these lines of listview itemclicklistener:-

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " + TextView[+position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        });
```